# How does dissolving LDPE in wax work?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, polymers, plastics

I was looking into machinable wax, and found it's based on dissolving LDPE into melted wax. While I understand the normal salt dissolving in water process, I'm not really sure how plastics can dissolve into wax. Do the plastic chains unravel and get suspended in the wax?

Here's a [video of the process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1tU4tLypBU).

Comment: With a salt the individuals will dissolve into the solvent.  In the case of LDPE the solvent molecules go into the LDPE until the LDPE molecules eventually become solvated.